# HTC: multiple notifications

Tags: notifications

I've recently bought HTC Desire and tried to setup all settings etc. But I have two problems:

1. Twitter notifications are delivered from Twitter app, HTC Twitter widget and something called Peep. Same message appears 2-3 times.
2. I've installed Skype. Is is possible not to receive notifications on Android if I have Skype turned on on PC? It's very annoying when I'm chatting with someone on Skype on PC and receive Android Skype notification every 20 seconds.

Comment: If you don't want to use multiple apps ... sign out of or remove all but one.

Answer (score 3):

1. No idea, not using twitter on my phone (@Matthew read's idea has merit)
2. Open skype, hit menu, Settings, uncheck notifications you don't want to see.